# Python - Error when adding data from list to a table

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-pptx, index-error

I have a list with a few records:

```
entries = ['Agenda', 'Measure 1', 'Measure 2']
```

I am trying to create a loop and have them added to a table as listed below:

```
for i in range(0, len(entries)):
    table.cell(i, 0).text = entries[i]
```

The below throws an `IndexError: list index out of range` on the last line, wondering where am I going wrong.

Comment: Could you show us an example of what `table` looks like?

Comment: Make sure your table size is big enough to accomodate `len(entries)`. Also do add the complete trace-back to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, when iterating over `range(len(something))` this is a red flag. There must be a better way.

If you need both the index as well as the value, you can use the built-in `enumerate()` function: `for i, val in enumerate(entries):`

The error you get means you're trying to access an element i that does not exist. The list elements should be accessible just fine - it's probably that `table.cell(i,0)`  does not exist. You can verify this by trying:

```
for i in range(0, len(entries)):
    print(entries[i]) # works
```

Compared to:

```
for i in range(0, len(entries)):
    print(table.cell(i, 0).text) # probably doesn't work
```

I used your old for loop to show that's not causing the error, but know that `range(len())` is a bad practice: it makes the code harder to read.

I'm not sure what kind of data structure you're using for `table`, but look up the related documentation and see how you should add new cells.